# Final field value not working in bytecode generation

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

I am trying to learn about how classes work.  I am trying to add a final field to my class using this code

```
    dout.writeShort(1);//field count
    dout.writeShort(Modifier.PUBLIC|Modifier.STATIC|Modifier.FINAL);//modifiers
    dout.writeShort(utfConstant("jjj"));//name
    dout.writeShort(utfConstant("I"));//signature
    dout.writeShort(1);//attribute count
    dout.writeShort(utfConstant("ConstantValue"));//constant value attribute
    dout.writeShort(2);//size of attribute
    dout.writeShort(intConstant(8));//value
```

But i am getting this error when i try to compile it

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Invalid ConstantValue field attribute length 131082 in class file Test
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
    at Bytecode.BytecodeTest$BytecodeClassLoader.buildClass(BytecodeTest.java:161)
    at Bytecode.BytecodeTest.makeClass(BytecodeTest.java:39)
    at Bytecode.BytecodeTest.buildClass(BytecodeTest.java:24)
    at Bytecode.BytecodeTest.main(BytecodeTest.java:17)
```

Here is my other code

```
private void writeConstantPool(DataOutputStream dout) throws IOException
    {
        dout.writeShort(poolIndex);

        for (Data data : poolMap) 
        {
            int tag = (byte) data.getData()[0];
            dout.writeByte(tag);

            switch (tag) 
            {
            case CONSTANT_Utf8:
                dout.writeUTF((String) data.getData()[1]);
                break;
            case CONSTANT_Class:
                dout.writeShort((Integer) data.getData()[1]);
                break;
            case CONSTANT_Integer:
                dout.writeInt((Integer) data.getData()[1]);
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }
    }

    private int utfConstant(String s)
    {
        return constant(CONSTANT_Utf8, s);
    }   

    private int intConstant(int i)
    {
        return constant(CONSTANT_Integer, i);
    }

    private int classConstant(String s) 
    {
        int classNameIndex = utfConstant(s.replace('.', '/'));
        return constant(CONSTANT_Class, classNameIndex);
    }

    private int constant(Object... data) 
    {
        Data constantData = new Data(data);

        if (poolMap.contains(constantData))
            return poolMap.indexOf(constantData)+1;

        poolMap.add(poolIndex-1, constantData);
        return poolIndex++;
    }

    private final Stack<Data> poolMap = new Stack<Data>();
    private int poolIndex = 1;

    private static class Data
    {
        private Object[] data;

        public Data(Object... data)
        {
            this.data = data;
        }

        public Object[] getData()
        {
            return data;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object o)
        {           
            if(o instanceof Data)
            {
                Data other = (Data) o;
                return Arrays.equals(data, other.getData());
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

The way im doing this is by generating all the methods and fields and then generating the constant pool, and then i am putting the constant pool in the byte array before the methods and fields.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong i could show more code if necessary, additionally i think the problem might be with intConstant or the constant value attribute.

After looking at this with a bytecode editor it looks like the intConstant method works fine so i think it is the field code that isnt working.  Also i looked at a constant in a bytecode editor and it looked the same i am confused.

Comment: I once had to work with bytcode manipulation and what I did was to write a simple java class containing the source code equivalent of what I wanted to do in bytecode. I compiled that class and then used javap to see what the bytecode is. Also the JVM spec can be very helpful.

Comment: i know i have tried both and i have looked at constant value attribute in bytecode and i still cant see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Could you post the classfile itself? I could take a look to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `length` of an attribute is supposed to be a 32-bit integer, not a 16-bit short.

Comment: Good catch. Even with experience, it's hard to spot these things.